# SimpleCursorAdapter IllegalArgumentException

Tags: c#, android, simplecursoradapter

I am currently doing Android programming using Visual Studio 2010 and C#. I have an error when compiling:  `Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException:` somebody can fix this?

Here is my code:

```
         void GetCursorView()
          {
             Android.Database.ICursor icTemp = sql.GetRecordCursor();
             if (icTemp != null)
             {
             icTemp.MoveToFirst();
             ListView lvTemp = FindViewById(Resource.Id.lvtemp);
             string[] from = new string[] { "id", "fname", "age", "addr" };
              int[] to = new int[] {
              Resource.Id.t1,
              Resource.Id.t2,
              Resource.Id.t3,
              Resource.Id.t4
                };
          // creating a SimpleCursorAdapter to fill ListView object.
             SimpleCursorAdapter scaTemp = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,Resource.Layout.recordview, icTemp, from, to); //error on this line
                     lvTemp.Adapter = scaTemp;
                            }
                        else
                         {
                         text.Text = sql.Message;
                            }
                      }
```

Here is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget35"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvtemp"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="147dp"
        android:background="#ff999999"
        android:padding="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_x="22dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp" 
        />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="268dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:hint="ID"
        android:layout_x="27dp"
        android:layout_y="157dp" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="264dp"
        android:layout_height="22dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:layout_x="30dp"
        android:layout_y="204dp" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t3"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="age"
        android:layout_x="31dp"
        android:layout_y="244dp" />
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_width="269dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Address"
        android:layout_x="30dp"
        android:layout_y="282dp" />
      <

        Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="OK"
            android:layout_x="77dp"
            android:layout_y="324dp" />

    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: How are you using c# to code for ANDROID, a Java programming language?? And your error is for Java, yet you say you're using c#? Dafuq?

Comment: Because C# code can be converted as "JAVA" codes using Xamarin mono for android .NET framework.

Comment: Ah, you should include this in your question.

Comment: sorry sir im new in this forum. but can you answer my question??

Comment: I am not sure, sorry. Someone who does know will answer it!

Comment: ok sir thanks.....i need this to fix couz my boss will terminate me ahhaah just joking

Comment: Your boss will "terminate" you probably because you use `AbsoluteLayout` and also you don't know that you should always provide the full stacktrace with the exception(to see what is the cause for that exception).

Answer (score 0):

i think instead of

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scaTemp = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,Resource.Layout.recordview, icTemp, from, to);
```

do

```
SimpleCursorAdapter scaTemp = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, icTemp,Resource.Layout.recordview, from, to);
```

Comment: Unhandled Exception: Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: